# Miroring usb drives (master/slave, booting linux from them)

Tags: linux, backup, boot, usb, mirror

I have a small server that boots from a usb drive and i would like to protect myself from the drive dying. I can't add another hard drive.

My question is: can i add one or two usb sticks of the same size and mirror the first one, so i can just unplug the first one when it dies and just reboot? I'd like to avoid reinstalling everything.

I am ok with a hourly or daily "backup" as long as i don't have to shutdown access to the server.

Thank you very much for your time and advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Linux you *can* RAID USB devices. Google for `mdadm` and your distribution name to get to know how.

For linux there's no difference between USB block device and a SATA block device, so you just have to follow a regular tutorial.